# Changing chart position dojo

Tags: dojox.charting

How can we change the position of chart in dojo?
I cannot change the position of piechart.

```
chart.addPlot("pttt",  {
    type: Pie,
    radius:50,
    htmlLabels: false           //See the code on jsfiddle
});
```

[Jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/vusan/6JfHQ/)

Comment: Do you want to display both charts the same plot? The idea of create multiple plots in the same chart is for example, an histogram where you have columns and also lines.

But in this case, you have to create two differents charts, as you can see in this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6JfHQ/2/

Comment: No, I have to create two on same chart because I need it to export in image format later not just to show on browser.

Comment: When you add various plots on the same chart, it's imposible show the charts separate, because when you create the chart you have to specify the chart container (the div where the chart will be displayed) that is the same for all the plots. You can export x number of charts on a same image. I don´t know what languages are you using on the backend side, but I did that in Java, exporting 6 differents charts on the same image